# How to use geom_text position_stack as part of its aes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 y=c(2,3,5,9,9),
                 label=c('blah1','blah2','blah3','blah4','blah5'),
                 vjust=c('top','bottom','top','bottom','top'),
                 posVjust=c(0.9,1.1,0.9,1.1,0.9),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

and can plot it directly like so:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,label=label)) + geom_point() + geom_line() +
         geom_text(aes(vjust=vjust))
p
```

However, I'd like to use the `posVjust` column as part of `geom_text`'s `aes` but I can't like so:

```
geom_text(aes(vjust=vjust,position=position_stack(vjust=posVjust)))
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: position
> p
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type     
PositionStack/Position/ggproto. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5): vjust,   
  position, x, y, label
```

Is there a way to use my `posVjust` column as part of the `position_stack` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position` isn't an aesthetic and goes outside of `aes`. As far as I know, `position_stack` takes a single value, rather than a vector. However, you could change `posVjust` to be `posVjust=c(-0.1,0.1,-0.1,0.1,-0.1)` and then do the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y,label=label)) + geom_point() + geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(y=y + posVjust))
```

You could also dispense with `posVjust` and just do:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y,label=label)) + geom_point() + geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(y=y + c(-0.1,0.1)))
```

You can add `vjust=vjust` as well, which will add a small additional increment of vertical offset.

Another option is to remove the points and just use labels instead of point markers. Offsetting the `geom_text` labels then becomes unnecessary. For example:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label)) + 
  geom_line(linetype="12", colour="grey50") +
  geom_text() +
  theme_bw()
```